# easy way to spilt a string like this in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

Now I have strings in the form `"temp:10"` and I use `temp=$(echo $str|awk '{split($0,array,":")} END{print array[1]}')` to split which is overkilled and slow..there must be a simpler to do this?

Comment: The answer by tom is the most optimum, but one more point: `awk '{split($0,array,":")} END{print array[1]}')` is overkill in its own. You can use `awk -F: '{print $1}'` to achieve same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use bash's parameter expansion with suffix removal:

```
temp=${str%%:*}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's also the `read` command:

```
$ str="temp:10"
$ IFS=: read before after <<< "$str"
$ echo "$before"
temp
$ echo "$after"
10
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you need the value before the `:`, `temp` in this example. If so, then you can use the `cut` command:

```
cut -d':' -f1
```